# Footer disappear - Disable all the widgets but no use - Run on Genesis framework

Tags: wordpress, footer, genesis

My site is http://khuyenmaitonghop.com/ - running on Genesis, Magazine Pro Theme

Just now I enter some PHP tag to a text widget. After that, all of my widget at footer disappear. I freaked out and disabled all the plugins. No use.

I put the theme back to Twenty Fourteen, the footer widget appear as usual.

I turned on the debug but nothing useful there ..

I do not know what to do? Please help me. If I need to provide any info, please let me know. I am newbie here and I may not be able to describe the problem so well.

Thank you so muchh,

Tuan

Comment: did you remove the php from the text widget?

Comment: You cannot use PHP code in text widget, I guess.

Comment: Please see view source, do you get any error printed over there at bottom?

Comment: @manishie: I did turn off all the plugin and remove all the widget. No use...

Comment: @Vidhi: I saw no error printed at the bottom ...

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate all plugins in MySQL like this:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = '' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

The wp_options table will also be the place to look for that erroneous PHP code. The following query will bring up the entries containing the configuration for each widget (one entry per widget):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE 'widget_%';
```

Then, edit the option_value in the row which corresponds to the widget that was causing the problems.